# Using led screen of a mobile phone on raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, led

I have an old led panel (ONLY) from my old phone. I was thinking about the way to connect it to my raspberry pi 3 and use it as its screen. Is it possible? If i could, what should i do. Thank you all in advance

Comment: Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, no. As far as I know an LCD panel requires a driver chip or board to convert input signals for display, and many manufacturers/models use a different driver chip. Plus a linux-compatible software driver compiled for the RPi is needed to communicate with it. All this is possible but time-consuming and outside of my knowledge.

I have had great success taking apart old portable TVs though (be careful of the high voltage parts) and using the screen + driver board on my RPi. If the driver board accepts HDMI input or RCA video then it's just a matter of making up a lead.

Alternatively there are small LCD panels and even touchscreens available to buy online, which can interface with the RPi's DSI (Display Serial Interface) ribbon connector or I2C/GPIO pins.